# Multiple aggregates in Ingres SQL

Tags: sql, ingres

I have a large table which is split into school years,

```
sch_year_id i4
name c20
addr1 c20
teacher c20

etc. etc..
```

sch_year_id is an integer, 23 represents the 13/14 school year, 24 represents the 14/15, etc. etc.

So there are normally thousands of records with the same sch_year_id but for different children.

I want to know the most recent (i.e. max) sch_year_id that contains the most records, but only where the number of records against that sch_year_id is more than 5000.

I can get a listing of the this using a GROUP BY and HAVING as below

```
select sch_year_id, count(*)
from table
group by sch_year_id
having count(*) > 5000
```

This return about 10 results, different school years, but I want the max(sch_year_id) of this result set.  If I add a max function around sch_year_id in the SELECT, nothing changes in the results.

I can do it with a derived table, as below

```
select max(a.sch_year_id)
from (select sch_year_id, count(*)
from table
group by sch_year_id
having count(*) > 5000) a
```

Or use a CTE, but I feel there must be a way of doing it without this?

Comment: I guess you could do it with a windowing function -- is that what you are asking about?  Still need the sub-query, so only useful if you are doing partitioning IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in Ingres, you can use `first`:

```
select first 1 sch_year_id
from t
group by sch_year_id
having count(*) > 5000
order by sch_year_id desc;
```

Comment: That query returns the error ' Column 'first' not found in any specified table', but 'select first 1', or 'top 1' works. It does not like 'first' without specifying a number! Thanks!

Comment: @BenHamilton . . . LOL.  Yes, the number is really important for this syntax.  Cheers.

Comment: When I read your answer originally, I wondered whether you could say 'select first col1' and it would know you just wanted the first one, but no, it wants the number.